# What is the purpose of this construct in ARM64 assembly, compiled from Swift on macOS - sequence of adrp, ldr, br instructions

Tags: macos, assembly, arm64, disassembly

While looking through disassembly of the SwiftUI app, I keep seeing these constructs:

```
->  0x100237af4 <+0>: adrp   x16, 29
    0x100237af8 <+4>: ldr    x16, [x16, #0xcb0]
    0x100237afc <+8>: br     x16
```

It seems like the address is taken from the next page in memory and then a jump is made there (or a `br`-anch.)

What is the purpose of these?

Answer (score 2):

These are import stubs.

Long story short, when you call a function defined in the same binary, the linker can just turn that into a direct `bl` instruction, but when you call a function in another binary, that's not usually possible. For one, you don't know where that binary is gonna be in memory relative to yours thanks to ASLR, and while you could in theory resolve this by rewriting the instruction at load-time (I believe x86_64 kexts do this), that would violate Apple's strict codesigning policy on arm64, and you'd still be limited to ±128MB, which is nowhere near enough to even reach all of the Apple libraries in the dyld_shared_cache.

So what the linker does instead is emit a sequence as you've shown, and make the `bl` go there. The stub then loads the address of the real function from a data page (which is not affected by codesigning, and thus can be modified at load-time) and branches to it.

If and when the import is resolved (i.e. the pointer on that data page is updated to its final value) depends on a few factors including architecture (arm64 vs arm64e), toolchain version, whether the symbol is marked as a weak import, etc.
In general though, symbols are either bound lazily or non-lazily. In the former case, all function pointers are initially set to point to a function in dyld, which will do the actual resolving the first time the import is used (if at all). In the latter case, all imports are resolved by dyld at load-time.
In recent years, Apple has been increasingly moving to the latter model, since it allows them to make the page(s) containing the function pointers readonly before the main binary runs, which can harden security a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It makes sense now. I'm wondering, if BSD/macOS has modules in memory like Windows does? Also, just a comment. If there's a way to divert execution from a signed code section via an indirect jump to an address from a non-signed data section, wouldn't it make the whole idea of code signing moot?

Comment: @c00000fd idk what you mean by "modules", but binaries need to be loaded into memory by necessity if they are to be executed. And no, codesigning is in most cases a prerequisite for control flow integrity, but without CFI, you will always have bare return addresses on the stack anyway, so ROP is always possible.